# AngularJS : How to use $state.go to pass querystring in nested state routing

Tags: angularjs-routing

How can I use `$state.go` to pass a query string into nested state routing?

**Code:**

```
 .state('masterform', {
        url: "/masterform?action&assetId&contentTypeId&folderid",
                views: {
                    content: {
                        templateUrl: 'components/masterform/masterform.html',
                        controller: 'masterformCtrl as masterform'
                    }
                }
            })
            .state('masterform.access', {
                url: "/access",
                views: {
                    content: {
                        templateUrl: 'components/masterform/access/access.html',
                        controller: 'accessCtrl as access'
                    }
                }
            })
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can simply pass query string parameters with second option of `$state.go()`.
Like:

```
$state.go('masterform', {action:'Get', assetId:1234, folderId:999});
```

Comment: please note that you will probably need to update application `$stateProvider`, like: `$stateProvider.state('Get', { params: { assetId: -1, folderId: -1}})`.